# Unspecified error/"Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not registered" on Windows XP 32 bit, MS-Access 2002

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, connection, oledb, provider

I have a VB.NET WinForm application, in which an OLEDB connection to a MS Access 2002 database is opened as follows:

```
Private Function MakeNewConnection(FullPath) As OleDbConnection
    Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
    Try
        Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + FullPath
        Conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return Conn
End Function
```

While this works fine generally, it generates an error **sporadically** on a Windows XP 32 bit machine (SP3). It's sproradical, because sometimes it works perfect, sometimes it throws simply an error! There are two types of messages: Unspecified error or the 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. You'll find the stack trace of the exception at the end of this post.

I've already done a lot of search. The "provider" error has mostly to do with 64 bit windows. In my case, it's a 32 bit system!

Any idea?

Errors in detail:

```
Error message: Unspecified error
Stack trace:    
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr,      OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
at QueryAgent.MakeNewConnection()    

Error message: the 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine
Stack trace:    at  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr,  DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
at QueryAgent.MakeNewConnection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change build option's build to your system (32 bit) from any CPU option.
go to Build>>>Configure>>>then change build option from AnyCPU to your system specific!
Also you download version 12 of OLE-DB from Microsoft. It will help if you are using higher version of MS Access in VS because that's how I can across the error originally (using multiple OS and software).
NOTE: when moving to higher version of a software, maintain an old copy (backup) because if one's tailored by newer version, it may be not usable in older version.

Comment: Please don't abbreviate in your answers. You're not txting.